# Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError on extending DataMediaSource

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin

I am trying to implement own `MediaDataSource` to decrypt videos on runtime. But I have a problem on very early stage: I just created class inherit it from `MediaDataSource`.
Here is the code:

```
    class SimpleSource : Android.Media.MediaDataSource
    {
            private string v;

            public SimpleSource(string v)
            {
                 this.v = v;
            }

            public override long Size
            {
                 get
                 {
                      throw new NotImplementedException();
                 }
            }

            public override int ReadAt(long position, byte[] buffer, int offset, int size)
            {
                  throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            public override void Close()
            {
                  throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
     }
```

And when I am calling `var source = new SimpleSource("fname.ax");` it throws `Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError` in constructor.

I tried it to run on android 4.1, 4.4 and 5.1.1 but got the same result.

[Exception screenshot on android 4.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjoha.png)

[Exception screenshot on android 5.1.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YnEr.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Now with the release of API 23, Android allows you to create a class that derives from MediaDataSource*

Your devices are lower API level than required.

Comment: Oh, It's true. I wasted three days because of inattention while reading [https://medium.com/@jacks205/implementing-your-own-android-mediadatasource-e67adb070731#.ruqaj0s2b](original article).

Comment: I mean [original article](https://medium.com/@jacks205/implementing-your-own-android-mediadatasource-e67adb070731#.ruqaj0s2b)